# Refreshing contents of a semantic-ui dropdown from remote server

Tags: javascript, mongoose, semantic-ui

My semantic-ui dropdown box doesn't refresh its contents from the remote server  unless I close the tab and revisit the site. A simple page refresh doesn't work to show new values in the dropdown, and ideally I wouldn't even need to do that.

**Form Script**

```
$('#create-button')
    .click(function () {
        $('#issue-type')
            .dropdown({
                clearable: true,
                apiSettings: {
                    url: '/api/tasktypes'
                }
            });
        $('#issue-modal').modal('show');
});
```

With this, I would have thought that every time the Create button is pressed it would have made the api call. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

I did try adding `cache: false` and `saveRemoteData: false` per the semantic documentation, but I didn't notice a difference. I felt that part was a little vague though, so I could have been doing it wrong.

What am I not understanding about these calls, or what am I missing?

To be clear, I am seeing values from my remote server. It's just if I add a value I don't see that in the dropdown until I kill the tab and reopen it.

Comment: With `cache:false` and `saveRomoteDate: false` we would be preventing from using the same data (saved in Session Storage) after refreshing de page. I think there is no a mechanism to request data on every click we would have to do it manually, sush as jQuery.